# Octopress include code doesn't take effect when using with arguments 'range', 'start','end'

Tags: octopress

Octopress official document says it supports a syntax:

```
{% include_code [title] [lang:language] path/to/file [start:#] [end:#] [range:#-#] [mark:#,#-#] [linenos:false] %}
```

But it takes no effect when I insert the below code into my blog.

```
{% include_code octopress_install_and_config.sh range:5-16 %}

File /Users/***/octopress/source/downloads/code/range:5-16 could not be found.
```

Are there any problems？

Answer (score 0):

After reading the source code '*plugins/include_code.rb*', I found that there has no any 'range', 'start' or 'end' function, even not a word matched one of these three on that file.